# how to set resizability to false using Scene Builder - Gluon?

Tags: gluon

Every time I go to Pane Layout > Extras, I find a checkbox to set resizability to true or false but it cannot be accessed for some reason. So, can you find me any solutions for this problem?

[This is the thing that happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHdw0.png)

I expect gluon to actually enable that portion but I am unable find any solution.